# Manage async operations in a sequential flow with bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

First off, I am not gonna deny that I am very new to promises and trying to get better at managing promises in my new Node.js app. I am using bluebird based on what I heard from friends and community. Here is a scenario:

The app has a sign up flow, a typical use case where in the following events have to occur in order to sign up a new user:

1. Check if a user already exists.
2. If not, add a new user.
3. Send a verification email.

I do have 3 separate functions addressing each of the above steps.

Now here is what I have come up with using promises flow...but somehow am not convinced with the code below:

```
user.isExistingUser(email)
        .then((successData) => {
            if(successData && successData.length === 0) {
                user.signUp(signUpInfo)
                .then((successData) => {
                    emailService.sendVerificationEmail(recipientInfo)
                    .then((successData) => {
                     res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(successData));
                    })
                    .catch((errorObj) => {
                        res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, null, errorObj));
                    });
                })
                .catch((errorObj) => {
                    res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, null, errorObj));
                });
            } else {
                res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, [{
                    param: 'email',
                    msg: 'An account already exists with this email'
                }], null));
            }
        })
        .catch((errorObj) => {
            res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, null, errorObj));
        });
```

As you may see the code seems a bit too long and can become a bit tricky to track. Can some bluebird expert here help with with a better or more  readable code?

Comment: does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/18dbrwxv/1/) help

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for a quick response...I am wondering what would happen if the email verification steps fails...can any error be caught in .catch block at the end? also I was wondering if I can use the .mapseries api in bluebird?

Comment: yes, single catchblock would catch any rejections - I don't know bluebird promise sugar, I use native promises exclusively - despite bluebirds phenomenal apparent performance advantage - not sure why you'd use it in this case though

Comment: You need to return all your nested promises from within the `.then()` handlers you start them in.  So, change `user.signUp(signUpInfo)....` to `return user.signUp(signUpInfo)...` and so on.  Every nested promise needs to be returned so they properly chain and propagate errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make better use of chaining. Always `return` promises from your functions that do something asynchronous.

```
user.isExistingUser(email).then(successData => {
    if (successData && successData.length === 0) {
        return user.signUp(signUpInfo).then(() => {
//      ^^^^^^
            return emailService.sendVerificationEmail(recipientInfo);
//          ^^^^^^
        }).then(successData => {
            res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(successData));
        });
    } else {
        res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, [{
            param: 'email',
            msg: 'An account already exists with this email'
        }], null));
    }
}).catch(errorObj => {
    res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, null, errorObj));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Unserstand what is wrong with your code**

Basically, your code is nested callback. Typical nested callback goes like this:

```
funcation(args.., 
    function(args..., 
        function(args){...}
    ){...}
){...}
```

Yours goes like:

```
function(args).then(()=> {
   function(args).then(() => {
       function(args){...}
   })
})
```

Not much difference, isn't it?

---

**This is the proper way of using Promise.**

The key to solve your problem is to chain the promise. This is actually the whole point of promise.

Basically, you want your `then` callback to return a promise. This way you can chain your promise to avoid the nested callback style of code.

Every `.then` method alway returns a promise itself.

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(()=> {
    // callback 
    return promiseC
});
```

If `callback` return a promise like above, effectily you can think of `promiseB = promiseC`. Now, if we have

```
promiseC = promiseA.then(()=> {
    // callback 
    return promiseB
});
promiseE = promiseC.then(()=> {
    // callback 
    return promiseD
});
```

You can **chain** them together. Then the above can be shorten as:

```
promiseA.then(()=> {
    // callback 
    return promiseB
}).then(()=> {
    // callback 
    return promiseD
});
```

---

**To answer you question directly.**

```js
let userPromise = user.isExistingUser(email); 

// handle new user
userPromise
.then((userData) => {
  assert userData.length === 0;
  // sign up
  // Assuming user.signUp is a Promise with recipientInfo as its resolved value
  return user.signUp(userData.signUpInfo); 
})
.then((recipientInfo)=> {
  // send verification email
  // Assuming user.sentVerificationEmail is a Promise with emailSuccessData as its resolved value
  return user.sentVerificationEmail(recipientInfo)
})
.then((emailSuccessData)=> {
  res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(emailSuccessData));
})
// if any of the previous Promise is rejected, 
// the follow .then will be effectively bypassed and fall though to this catch
.catch((err)=> {
  res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, null, err));
})


// handle existing user
userPromise.then((successData) => {
  assert successData.length > 0
  const json = [{ 
    param: 'email', 
    msg: 'An account already exists with this email'
  }]
  res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, json, null));
}); 
// no need to catch again. if userPromise is rejected, it will be handled by the catch above.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess one reasonable way of implementing the same code could be like;

```
user.isExistingUser(email)
    .then(successData => successData &&
                         successData.length === 0 ? user.signUp(signUpInfo)
                                                        .then(successData => emailService.sendVerificationEmail(recipientInfo))
                                                        .then(successData => res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(successData)))
                                                  :  res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, [{param: 'email', msg: 'An account already exists with this email'}], null)))
    .catch(err => res.json(responseUtility.getApiResponse(null, null, err)));
```